# Unable to parse 2 dimensional json data using jquery sent from server using php

Tags: php, jquery, json

```
$.post('ol_st_checker.php',function(d){              //this method is going to check who ever is online
    $.each(d.uinfo,function(index,value) {
        alert(index+'='+value);
       /*$.each(this,function(index, element) {
            alert(index+'='+element);
        });*/
    });
},'json');},
```

The data sent to the browser using PHP json_encode looks as shown below:

```
[{"uinfo":{"0":"1","status":"1","1":"1001","user_id":"1001","2":"2013-05-09 22:24:10","last_update":"2013-05-09 22:24:10"}}]
```

In the alert box, I'm getting "undefined", but when I try to display an alert after the post function, I'm getting the above output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this
`d` is an array. `d[0].uinfo` is object you trying to access.

```
$.post('ol_st_checker.php',function(d){              //this method is going to check who ever is online
    $.each(d[0].uinfo,function(index,value) {
        alert(index+'='+value);
       /*$.each(this,function(index, element) {
            alert(index+'='+element);
        });*/
    });
    },'json');},
```

Comment: Thank you its working , how to retrive data if there are rows in d[0].uinfo